# mrtg not allowing me to view various devices

Tags: ubuntu, cisco, mrtg

I'm running mrtg on ubuntu to monitor my  Cisco switches, and it works fine for one device. However, when I attempt to add a second switch, the index.html file created by mrtg only shows me information regarding the latest switch added, and not both switches together.

I use the following commands to add a new device...

```
cfgmaker --global 'WorkDir:/var/www/mrtg' --global 'Options[_]: bits,growright' --output /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg public@<ip address of my switch>
env LANG=C mrtg /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
indexmaker --output=/var/www/mrtg/index.html /etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
```

But whenever I add a new device this way, the /var/www/mrtg/index.html file only displays details of the last added device, not an accumulation of all devices.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that you're overwriting mrtg.cfg every single time you're running `cfgmaker`, if you check your mrtg.cfg you'll see that the data there is only the data related to your latest switch.

In order to overcome this problem you can do several things
 * Merge the mrtg files manually
 * Have one mrtg.cfg file per device and one directory on the web server per device, so you can use indexmaker to do each

If you want anything a bit more complicated I would strongly recommend to move up a notch and try to install cacti (http://www.cacti.net/), it'll make all this so much easier, specially if you start to manage enough devices